# Show count on every row that counts how many rows there are based on certain conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm curious whether you know how to easily select a COUNT of how many 'children' there are within a 'parent', and show this on every row while maintaining the child as the unique key of the table.

Currently I select my table like this:

```
SELECT OBJECTID, PARENTID
FROM CURRENTTABLE
```

This is the result that I get:

```
CURRENTTABLE:
OBJECTID, PARENTID
OBJECT1, PARENT1
OBJECT2, PARENT1
OBJECT3, PARENT2
OBJECT4, PARENT2
OBJECT5, PARENT2
```

But I want it to look like this, because there are 2 objects within Parent1 and 3 objects within Parent2

```
CURRENTTABLE:
OBJECTID, PARENTID, COUNTOBJECTSWITHINPARENT
OBJECT1, PARENT1, 2
OBJECT2, PARENT1, 2
OBJECT3, PARENT2, 3
OBJECT4, PARENT2, 3
OBJECT5, PARENT2, 3
```

Any ideas how to do this easily?

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: Have you looked a `COUNT` and the `OVER` clause? If not, what have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: A simple subquery can do this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECTID, 
PARENTID,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PARENTID) as COUNTOBJECTSWITHINPARENT
FROM CURRENTTABLE
```